# How to separate website code as per as restfull webservice code base within cakephp3.0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am creating  a website using cakephp3.0 . here is 2 section

1) Website 
2) rest-full Web-service for mobile app

I do not know how to create both thing within single project because for this i need to create separate model and controller for both. so I want to know .How can do it in cakephp3.0

I think , I need to create separate module for web-service
suppose I have a user section so please tell me how to I can create both ?

I am very new on cakephp3.0

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html - this will help.

Comment: `i need to create separate model [...] for both` - no you don't =). Once you know/realise that, it should be clear you only need separate controllers and routes. The use of plugins ^ can help you.

Answer (score 2):

> I am very new on cakephp3.0

Do [the tutorials](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples.html) and [read the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/index.html) - Start reading from the very beginning and not just random pages. And pay attention to what you read, don't just scan over the pages.

> I think , I need to create separate module for web-service suppose I have a user section so please tell me how to I can create both ?

No, you don't have to do that, read these two sections. Your question is far too broad and all you need is explained in detail there.

- [JSON/XML Views](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html)
- [REST in CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/rest.html)

A huge part of the job as a programmer is reading (and writing) documentation, CakePHP has an excellent documentation I recommend you to use it.